# Is the integrated Bash terminal in VS Code different from the Bash terminal on my operating system? (Ubuntu 20.4)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Installed Go compiler using the VS Code integrated terminal. The compiler works fine due to the fact that the command "go version" typed in the integrated terminal correctly gives the version.

```
go version go1.21.1 linux/amd64
```

However, the command is not recognised when I use the normal Bash terminal on my operating system (Ubuntu 20.4).

```
Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install go         # version 1.21.1, or
sudo apt  install golang-go  # version 2:1.13~1ubuntu2
sudo apt  install gccgo-go   # version 2:1.13~1ubuntu2
```

I installed Visual Studio Code using the Ubuntu Software store.

How do I fix the VS Code terminal so that software installed in my integrated terminal reflects in the actual OS system?

Comment: Had a similar problem some time ago and it was due to [confinement / security sandbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917049/what-is-the-classic-mode-of-snap-and-why-do-some-snaps-not-install-without-it) as I had installed VSCode using snap and a wrong option....

Comment: show the output of `whereis go` in your VS Code terminal and the output of `echo $PATH` in your GNOME terminal. It could be a environment modification contributed by an extension. See if you can use `go version` in VS Code if you reload with extensions disabled.

Comment: @starball I echod the path of my go compiler. It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I added Add /usr/local/go/bin to the PATH environment variable

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin